# GCE Network Load Balancer loops traffic back to VM

Tags: networking, google-compute-engine, nlb

On GCE, using a Network Load Balancer (NLB), I have the following scenario:

```
1 VM with internal IP of 10.138.0.62 (no external IP)
1 VM with internal IP of 10.138.0.61 (no external IP)
1 NLB with a target pool (Backend) that contains both of these VMs
1 Health check that monitors a service on these VMs
```

The simple issue is that when one of these VMs hits the NLB IP address, the request is immediately resolved to the IP of the same instance making the request, it never gets balanced between the two VMs, it never makes it to the other VM.  Even if the VM making the request has failed its health check.  For example:

```
VM on 10.138.0.62 is in target pool of NLB and its service is healthy.
VM on 10.138.0.61 is in target pool of NLB and its service is NOT healthy.
```

Make a request from the second VM, on 10.138.0.61, to the NLB, and even though this same VM has failed its health check, traffic will still be delivered to itself.  It's basically ignoring the fact there's a NLB and health checks entirely, and simply saying, "If the VM is in the target pool for this NLB and it attempts contact with the IP of the NLB, loop the traffic back to itself".

Note that if I remove the VM on IP 10.138.0.61 from the target pool of the NLB and try the connection again, it immediately goes through to the other VM that's still in the target pool, just like I'd expect it to.  If I put the VM on IP 10.138.0.61 back in the target pool and attempt to hit the NLB, again it will only loop back to the calling machine on 10.138.0.61

Googling around a bit, I saw that this behavior happens on some versions of Windows Server and its NLB, but I didn't expect this on GCE.  Have others seen the same behavior?  Is this just a known behavior that I should expect?  If so, any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working as intended. Due to how networks are configured in a virtual environment, this will always result in the load balanced VM returning the request to itself ignoring health check status. Please check the [link](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/internal/setting-up-internal#test-from-backend-vms) provided for more information.

Comment: Ah, I wondered why I didn't find it when I looked in the docs before, but it's under the heading "Internal TCP/UDP Load Balancing".